# MIDI Controller with an ATmega328p

Tags: microcontroller, avr, midi

Could one detect presses and releases from a 11 by 6 matrixed keyboard and send data from USART with just an ATmega328p microcontroller? I want to send MIDI notes from an old 61 key Yamaha keyboard that is not velocity sensitive.

Comment: Do you have the skills and knowledge?

Comment: Good question. First I was going to answer a sarcastic "yes." or "no." depending on the pin counts alone, but someone has to actually figure this out from the datasheet because it's pretty darn close. It works if most of the pins can be used as a digital I/O.

Comment: @pipe Datasheet: 23 programmable I/O pins. Not even tight. 11x6->17 worst case (7 best case?) + RX + TX = 19. Leaves 4 to drive the LED Xmas tree. As a note to the OP, I didn't vote unclear. I voted too broad, because it is, even if it's answerable in several ways. In fact, that's the definition of too broad.

Comment: @Asmyldof And then you need one GPIO for the reset pin, two GPIO are taken by the external crystal you need for reasonably accurate MIDI timing, and let's hope that the last GPIO you have left isn't required for something else.. It's not as easy as you make it out to be. I've been caught by the manufacturer's GPIO exaggerations before.

Comment: @pipe The reset can be used as an GPIO pin and you can do it without a crystal, just means you need to do more thinkypain to save on the xtal if you want.

Comment: @Asmyldof The reset can obviously not be used as GPIO if your application needs a controlled reset. And the internal oscillator only has a 10% accuracy, and drifts a lot even if you trim it. I'm just saying that there are more things to think about than just reading "23 GPIO" and blindly saying _yes_ or _no_.

Comment: ["Charlieplexing"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charlieplexing#Input_data_multiplexing)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With 23 GPIO I don't see the problem: 11 + 6 GPIO for the (matrix) of keys, and one for the MIDI out. An ATmega328 is advertised as having 23 GPIO.

When you want to detect simultaneous kepresses you will need a diode at each key.

And when by 'key' you mean a switchover switch and you want to detect how fast a key is pressed you actually have twice as many keys, and things get complex. Maybe a charlieplexing scheme could still do that, but not a simple matrix.

Now (as Andy's comment hints) your actual questions is not 'can it be done' but rather 'can *I* do it': I don't know you, so I don't have the faintes idea. It would be a good end-of-first-year-project for one of my students. (But MIDI seems to be a bit out of fashion, so there were no takers for this suggestion.)